# Local minimum and maximums of function of 2 variables

Tags: calculus

we want to find all local extrema (and $minf$ and $maxf$) of the function:
$f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 3y^2$ on the disk$ D=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2 \leqslant 1 \right\} $.

For $x^2+y^2<1$ its obvious that we have $minf = 0 = f(0,0)$. Now for $x^2+y^2=1$ we can substitute inside the function the expression: $y^2=1-x^2$ to get :
$f(x) = 3-x^2 , x\in[-1,1]$. Setting the derivative equal to zero we get :
$ -2x=0 \Rightarrow x=0 $.

So we have $maxf= f(0)=3 $ and $minf= f(-1)=f(1)=2$. What can we imply for the locations : $(0,-1),(0,1)$ and $(-1,0),(1,0)$ of $f(x,y)$ ?

If we use lagrange multipliers how can we check whether 2 is a local minimum or maximum value of $f(x,y)$?

Thanks

Comment: Use the second derivative test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Answer (score 1):

At the actuating restriction we have

$$
\cases{
f(x,y) = 2x^2+3y^2\\
x^2+y^2 = 1
}\Rightarrow f(x, y(x)) = g(x) = 3-x^2
$$

Analogously we have $f(x(y),y) = g(y) = 2+y^2$

so it can be observed that at $x=0$ there is a local maximum and at $y=0$ we have a local minimum.

NOTE

Also can be used the bordered hessian [[bordered hessian]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)